# How to use smart pointer in this situation

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to use smart pointer in the following situation:

```
   SOME_STRUCT* ptr = new SOME_STRUCT;
   ptr->SOME_MEMBER = new BYTE[100];
   CallSomeAPI(ptr);
```

now the API can either return error or pass successfully but in both those  cases i want to delete the object , one way can be to write delete statement during error exit and during normal exit.

But how can i use a smart pointer for these pointers ?
By smart pointers i mean unique_ptr, shared_ptr , etc. whichever can work !

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use a `std::unique_ptr`? The new smart pointers shouldn't really be seen as a replacement for normal pointer, but more like handling ownership: Can a resource (memory, file, device, etc.) be owned by multiple owners (`std::shared_ptr`) or by only a single owner (`std::unique_ptr`) at a time?

Comment: Actually i want to use a smart pointer to automatically deallocate , not necessarily unique_ptr , my main objective is automatic cleanup and not ownership. I edited the question now to be more clear.

Comment: With the smart pointers you really *have* to think about ownership. For example, if you pass a `std::unique_ptr` to a function, the ownership is moved to that function and the object will be destructed once the function returns. If you use `std::shared_ptr` the object (or memory) will not be deleted until *all* copies of that shared pointer have been destructed, if there's one living on somewhere the memory will still be allocated.

Comment: @shaarang Cleanup == ownership. Ownership is pretty much defined as "responsibility for cleanup."

Comment: On an unrelated point, wouldn't it be better if the structure had a constructor and destructor that handle the allocation/deallocation of `SOME_MEMBER`?

Comment: Actually ownership must be "shared" here because this pointer gets passed to multiple APIs and so it must be destructed only in case of the scope of the function that constructed them leaves.

Comment: Actually its not something i have created , I am calling some windows api and its all related to that.so structure is sytem defined and cannot be modified.

Comment: The fact that a function takes a pointer does not imply that it must be allocated dynamically. Since you also say that the objects don't leave the function with that code, create both objects on the stack to get automatic cleanup.

Comment: @shaarang "only in case of the scope of the function that constructed them leaves" This actually describes unique ownership, not shared one. Shared ownership would be "I can pass the pointer on, then terminate, and as long as someone else holds the pointer, it will continue to live."

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think that should be an answer. Unless `SOME_STRUCT` is big or `100` can be much larger in practice, it would be the best solution. Wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: If the array is really big, it should still be cleaned up automatically, i.e. it should be a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  Although you dont need a pointer in that case, you can pass the address but the system defined structure has member BYTE* lp; so can you allocate that as well on stack? i dont think so and that member is the main problem for me not being able to use the smart pointer Angew: I am going through your answer will reply very soon on that.

Comment: `SOME_STRUCT s; std::vector<BYTE> buffer(100); s.SOME_MEMBER = &buffer[0]; CallSomeAPI(&s);` -- yes, this works.

Comment: Actually 100 is not fixed here , so i need to use new any way ! I posted this just to narrow down the question to specifics i wanted to ask !

Comment: @shaarang You don't need `new`, you can use a dynamically-sized container, like Ulrich suggests.

Comment: @Ulrich Don't be shy! Post an answer!

Comment: @Angew: You mean passing vector's address? and upon leaving the scope, vector object will get deleted automatically? right !

Comment: @shaarang Not the vector's address, the address of the first element in the vector. Ulrich's comment shows it.

Comment: oh yes i meant the same. but he edited the comment earlier he was using new BYTE[100];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you cannot modify `SMOE_STRUCT` to add a destructor to it. This leaves you with two options: a custom deleter, and encapsulation.

First, you could create a custom deleter for use with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
struct SOME_STRUCT_Deleter
{
  void operator() (SOME_STRUCT *p) const
  {
    delete[] p->SOME_MEMBER;
    delete p;
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<SOME_STRUCT, SOME_STRUCT_Deleter> ptr{new SOME_STRUCT};
ptr->SOME_MEMBER = new BYTE[100];
CallSomeAPI(ptr.get());
```

If you find that, unlike the situation described in your question, shared ownership would suit you better than exclusive one, you can use the deleter with a `shared_ptr` as well, like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<SOME_STRUCT> ptr{new SOME_STRUCT, SOME_STRUCT_Deleter{}};
ptr->SOME_MEMBER = new BYTE[100];
CallSomeAPI(ptr.get());
```

A second option, which I find preferable, is to wrap `SOME_STRUCT`:

```
struct SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus
{
  SOME_STRUCT s;
  ~SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus()
  {
    delete[] s.SOME_MEMBER;
  }

  SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus()
  {
    s.SOME_MEMBER = new BYTE[100];
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus> ptr{new SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus};
CallSomeAPI(&ptr->s);
```

You could even "wrap" it by making `SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus` derive from `SOME_STRUCT` instead of aggregating it, which would give you direct access to members without the need to go through `s`. At the same time, it could lead to memory leaks if someone cast `SOME_STRUCT_plus_plus*` to `SOME_STRUCT*` and then called `delete` on it.

Comment: I could have written the wrapper class but i dont prefer that , But i do like the custom deleter method more ;-) but can the same thing work with shared_ptr as well?

Comment: @shaarang Yes, it can work with `shared_ptr` too. You will have to provide the deleter object explicitly when creating the shared pointer, but you don't have to reflect its type in the type of the `shared_ptr`. Added to the answer.

Comment: But i prefer the deleter method , because that answers my question and i will be using this method based on the overall structure of my code.!

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom deleter for `unique_ptr`.

```
struct my_deleter {
    void operator()(SOME_STURCT* ptr) const {
        delete[] ptr->SOME_MEMBER;
        delete ptr;
    }
};

using my_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SOME_STRUCT, my_deleter>;
```

and I would suggest changing `new SOME_STRUCT;` to `new SOME_STRUCT{};` to default initialize `SOME_MEMBER` to `nullptr`.

I am not 100% happy with this solution, so perhaps look into `scope_guard` or writing a wrapper class for your struct.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it seems that all can be on the stack:

```
SOME_STRUCT ptr;         // or auto ptr = std::make_unique<SOME_STRUCT>();
BYTE bytes[100];         // or std::vector<BYTE> bytes(100);
ptr.SOME_MEMBER = bytes; // or ptr->SOME_MEMBER = bytes.data();
CallSomeAPI(&ptr);       // or CallSomeAPI(ptr.get());
```

Comment: :-)  its just narrowed down version of the question i present to you , the value 100 is not fixed and is actually [nCount] , so it can't be an answer.

Comment: Yes , just realized that vector<> can help put all on stack as well , even that can be the way ! thanks!